# How to get birthday date from Google in Django-allauth?

Tags: python, django, oauth, google-oauth, django-allauth

I am trying to get birthday date from Google oauth with Django-Allauth but I can't.

I read that I have to put the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", but nothing happen in extra_data field.

Can you help me?
Thank you

**Edited:**
Sample code:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
'facebook':
   {'SCOPE': ['publish_stream', 'email', 'user_birthday', 'user_location'],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'https'},
    'METHOD': 'oauth2',
    'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True},
'google':
    #{ 'SCOPE': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',],
    { 'SCOPE': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'],
      'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'access_type': 'online' },
       } }
```

On facebook is working, I have new extra_data info like birthday, gender, etc. But google not fillme the extra_data field with new info.

Comment: What did u tried? A code sample?

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of catering my use case in an academic project, I have [forked](https://github.com/biwin/django-allauth-underground) `django-allauth` to add some functionality which includes extra Google profile data,

You can install the package with pip

```
pip install django-allauth-underground
```

Configure Google scopes as

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    },
}
```

on successful signup, the extra data will be updated with some ***real extra data*** 
which can be accessed from `extra_data['people']`

Comment: Can you please give more details on its usage

Comment: @ManasKinkar Its for something academic i did years ago, its deprecated as of now.

Comment: Yeah, I faced some issues with it. Thanks for the reply.